# Adding an IPv4-only Domain Controller to an existing pool of Domain Controllers with both IPv6 and IPv4

Tags: domain-controller, ipv6, ipv4

We have an existing pool of Windows 2008 R2 Domain Controllers on-premises.  These Domain Controllers have IPv6 and IPv4 configured.

Now we need to add another Domain Controller that will seat on an EC2 machine.  EC2 does not support IPv6, so it has to be IPv4-only.

Just for the record, [Microsoft does not recommend](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Disable-IPV6-Domain-69c4ef31) disabling IPv6 on a Domain Controller that has it already enabled already enabled.

Are there any risks or caveats to take into account when adding an IPv4-only DC to an existing pool of DCs that are already configured with IPv4 and IPv6 enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Are there any risks or caveats to take into account when adding an IPv4-only DC to an existing pool of DCs that are already configured with IPv4 and IPv6 enabled?` - No.

Also, don't disable the IPv6 components on the new DC. The fact that EC2 doesn't support IPv6 is irrelevant to the configuration and operation of the actual DC.